# Bootstrap carousels won't scroll/load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I've been browsing boards and forums for a while trying to figure out why my carousel won't load/scroll.  I read about having to link to a popper.js file, read about loading jquery and popper before bootstrap, and quite a few other issues.  My console gives me no errors once I started loading the popper.js.  Can anyone see an issue in my HTML and tell me why the carousel won't scroll either automatically or with the use of the glyphicons?  When I click the carousel, it doesn't do anything, give me any errors or go to #theCarousel as it was doing before i loaded the popper js file.  I appreciate any help anyone can give.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<!-- If IE use the latest rendering engine -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<!-- Set the page to the width of the device and set the zoon level -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">

<title>Bootstrap Tutorial</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<style type="text/css">

/* Carousel Styling */
.slide1{
    background-image: url('./img/bkgrnd1.jpeg');
    height: 500px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
.slide2{
    background-image: url('./img/bkgrnd2.jpg');
    height: 500px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
.slide3{
    background-image: url('./img/bkgrnd3.jpg');
    height: 500px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
.slide1{
    background-image: url('./img/bkgrnd4.jpeg');
    height: 500px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
.carousel-caption h1{
    font-size: 5.4em;
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
    padding-bottom: .4em;
}
.carousel-caption p{
    font-size: 2em;
}
</style>

<body>

<div id="theCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="slide1"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Amazing Backgrounds</h1>
                <p>Thousands of Backgrounds for Free</p>
                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Get them now!</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="slide2"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>This is SLIDE TWOO</h1>
                <p>Thousands of SLIDE TWOS for Free</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="slide3"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Amazing ILLUSIONS</h1>
                <p>Thousands of SLIDE THREES for Free</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="slide4"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Amazing COLORS</h1>
                <p>Thousands of SLIDE FOURS for Free</p>
                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">BUTTON 4!</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: afaik, popper is for bootstrap 4. are u using the right bootstrap js version? ur css is version 3

Comment: You are right.  I was having issues using my own bootstrap css file, which i downloaded tonight, not sure what version it is.  So I linked to that and it fixed it.  But I just tried using v3 without popper and you're right, it doesn't need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

put all these top of the carousel because carousel needs this here is full answer i hope it will help you

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<!-- If IE use the latest rendering engine -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<!-- Set the page to the width of the device and set the zoon level -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">

<title>Bootstrap Tutorial</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<style type="text/css">

/* Carousel Styling */
.slide1{
    background-image: url('https://cloud.netlifyusercontent.com/assets/344dbf88-fdf9-42bb-adb4-46f01eedd629/68dd54ca-60cf-4ef7-898b-26d7cbe48ec7/10-dithering-opt.jpg');
    height: 500px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
.slide2{
    background-image: url('https://cloud.netlifyusercontent.com/assets/344dbf88-fdf9-42bb-adb4-46f01eedd629/68dd54ca-60cf-4ef7-898b-26d7cbe48ec7/10-dithering-opt.jpg');
    height: 500px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
.slide3{
    background-image: url('https://cloud.netlifyusercontent.com/assets/344dbf88-fdf9-42bb-adb4-46f01eedd629/68dd54ca-60cf-4ef7-898b-26d7cbe48ec7/10-dithering-opt.jpg');
    height: 500px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
.slide1{
    background-image: url('https://cloud.netlifyusercontent.com/assets/344dbf88-fdf9-42bb-adb4-46f01eedd629/68dd54ca-60cf-4ef7-898b-26d7cbe48ec7/10-dithering-opt.jpg');
    height: 500px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
.slide4{
    background-image: url('https://cloud.netlifyusercontent.com/assets/344dbf88-fdf9-42bb-adb4-46f01eedd629/68dd54ca-60cf-4ef7-898b-26d7cbe48ec7/10-dithering-opt.jpg');
    height: 500px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
.carousel-caption h1{
    font-size: 5.4em;
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
    padding-bottom: .4em;
}
.carousel-caption p{
    font-size: 2em;
}
</style>

<body>

<div id="theCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="slide1"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Amazing Backgrounds</h1>
                <p>Thousands of Backgrounds for Free</p>
                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Get them now!</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="slide2"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>This is SLIDE TWOO</h1>
                <p>Thousands of SLIDE TWOS for Free</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="slide3"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Amazing ILLUSIONS</h1>
                <p>Thousands of SLIDE THREES for Free</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="slide4"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Amazing COLORS</h1>
                <p>Thousands of SLIDE FOURS for Free</p>
                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">BUTTON 4!</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you. http://jsfiddle.net/r2wLz6xr/431/

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<div id="theCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

<ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
</ol>

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
 <div class="item active">
  <div class="slide1"></div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Amazing Backgrounds</h1>
            <p>Thousands of Backgrounds for Free</p>
            <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Get them now!</a></p>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="slide2"></div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>This is SLIDE TWOO</h1>
            <p>Thousands of SLIDE TWOS for Free</p>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="slide3"></div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Amazing ILLUSIONS</h1>
            <p>Thousands of SLIDE THREES for Free</p>
        </div>
</div> 
<div class="item">
<div class="slide4"></div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Amazing COLORS</h1>
            <p>Thousands of SLIDE FOURS for Free</p>
            <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">BUTTON 4!</a></p>
        </div>
        </div>
 </div>
<!-- Controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* Carousel Styling */
.slide1{
background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/700x700');
height: 500px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
}
.slide2{
background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/700x700');
height: 500px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
}
.slide3{
background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/700x700');
height: 500px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
}
.slide4{
background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/700x700');
height: 500px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
}
.carousel-caption h1{
font-size: 5.4em;
font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
padding-bottom: .4em;
}
.carousel-caption p{
font-size: 2em;
}
```